# r.default.acequire is not a function

Tags: sharepoint, spfx, react-ace

I have a problem with my task. Error message is: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KpXX1.png). Could please help me? I have tried so many way to solve this issue but I couldn't.

I have change my react-ace version and my expactation is solving this problem.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error message r.default.acequire is not a function suggests that there might be an issue with how you're using or importing the react-ace library in your React project.You need to update react to the latest version